# Visual Studio Team Services: Abandoned Builds

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to build a project and receiving the following error message hours after queuing the build:

> "The request was abandoned due to an infrastructure failure.
>   Notification of assignment to an agent was never received."

Is this a common occurrence with VSTS?  Is there something I can do to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not be a common occurrence. This happens when a request is queued long enough to be timed out by the system. I urge you to queue again.

Recently there has been a incident which could have impacted you. More details are present on this blog.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=12756